# Can I use a JSONPath expression to return a modified value of a matched element?

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have JSON that contains a value that is a string of pipe-separated key-value pairs that I need to pull a value from using JSONPath expression with a script.

I'm looking to return all the "Job Titles" found in the third position of the "Rows" object using JSONPath.

**Here is the original JSON**

```
{
  "DataSource": {
    "Rows": [
      [
        "Leslie Knope",
        "Eastern Standard Time",
        "USA",
        "Department:Parks and Recreation|Job Title:Project Manager|Email:leslie@pawnee.il.gov"
      ], 
      [
        "Ron Swanson",
        "Eastern Standard Time",
        "USA",
        "Department:Parks and Recreation|Job Title:Senior Project Manager|Email:ron@pawnee.il.gov"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

To select the details I need, I would use the JSONPath Expression "$.DataSource.Rows[*].3" and it would return:

```
[
  "Department:Parks and Recreation|Job Title:Project Manager|Email:leslie@pawnee.il.gov",
  "Department:Parks and Recreation|Job Title:Senior Project Manager|Email:ron@pawnee.il.gov"
]
```

I know that I can use regex to extract the value for "Job Title" and that Regex is "/(?<=Job Title:)(.*?)(?=[|]|$)/gm".

**Is there a way to use JSON path (along with Regex) to return only the values for 'Job Title' from the JSON?**

The output I'm looking for is:

```
[
  "Project Manager",
  "Senior Project Manager"
]
```

Is this possible to do this using JSONPath with a script? I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a  map function instead

```
var result = json.DataSource.Rows.map((element) => {
  return element[3].substring(
    element[3].indexOf("Title:") + 6,
    element[3].indexOf("Email:") - 1
  ); 
});
```

or if you want json path

```
var result = jsonPath(json, "$.DataSource.Rows[*].3").map((element) => {
  return element.substring(
    element.indexOf("Title:") + 6,
    element.indexOf("Email") - 1
  );
});
```